# Is there a way to put a vector into a pair in brackets

Tags: c++

So I would like to put this vector into a pair for animation states. However, obviously this doesn't work because apparently it doesn't match the argument list. So basically my question is, is there a way to create a vector in a pair without using brackets? Here's my code.

```
std::vector < std::pair < std::string, std::vector < int > > > animations ={
    std::make_pair("PlayerStand.png", { 0,0,0,0 })
};
```

I'm sure this question is very easy to any C++ experts, but I've searched through the vector argument list and have had no luck.

Comment: In the context of the `make_pair` call, the compiler can't deduce the type of `{ 0,0,0,0 }`. Or that the string should be `std::string` and not `const char*`.

Comment: Please don't separate your C++ code with that many spaces; it makes it rather difficult to read. At the very least, spaces shouldn't be used around :: or between a template name and its < starting angle bracket (comment copied from Nicol Bolas).

Comment: @bolov I dont think it should matter where I put my spaces. And personally, I think it's easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Braced initializer lists are typeless, and cannot be deduced when using with forwarding references, such as the ones used in `std::make_pair`'s constructor. You must explicitly type them:

```
std::pair < std::string, std::vector < int > > animations ={
    std::make_pair("PlayerStand.png", std::vector<int>{ 0,0,0,0 })
};
```

Comment: Since the type is already right there, using `{a, b}` instead of `make_pair` is also an option. That preserves the needed context to avoid attaching an explicit type to every list-initialized element in there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are already specifying the type of `animations` so you can just use brace initialization like this:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::vector<int>>> animations {
    {"PlayerStand.png", { 0,0,0,0 }}
};
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/K1bfvK).